# Error with comment detection using Regular Expression in java

Tags: java, regex, stack-overflow

I have create a simple code of comment detection.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class regex extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    JPanel center=new JPanel();
    JPanel title=new JPanel();
    JTextArea text=new JTextArea();
    JTextArea result=new JTextArea();
    JScrollPane sctext=new JScrollPane(text);
    JScrollPane scresult=new JScrollPane(result);
    JButton proc=new JButton("proccess");
    regex()
    {
        setSize(600,600);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(title,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        title.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
        title.add(new JLabel("code"));
        title.add(new JLabel("Regex"));
        add(center,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        center.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
        center.add(sctext);
        center.add(scresult);
        add(proc,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        proc.addActionListener(this);
        show();
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getSource()==proc)
        {
            try
            {
                result.setText("");
                Matcher m=Pattern.compile("(/\\*(.|[\\n]|(\\*+([^*/]|[\\r\\n])))*\\*+/)|(//.*)").matcher(text.getText());
                while(m.find())
                {
                    result.append(m.group()+"\n");
                }
            }
            catch(Exception x)
            {
                try
                {
                    File err = new File("error.txt");
                    java.io.PrintStream ps = new java.io.PrintStream(err);
                    x.printStackTrace(ps);
                    ps.close();
                }
                catch(Exception exx){}
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[]agrs)
    {
        new regex();
    }
}
```

I don't know why my code can't detect long comments.

I have a sample of text that contain long comment.

```
/*
 * The Apache Software License, Version 1.1
 *
 * Copyright (c) 1999-2003 The Apache Software Foundation.  All rights 
 * reserved.
 *
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
 * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
 * are met:
 *
 * 1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
 *    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer. 
 *
 * 2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
 *    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in
 *    the documentation and/or other materials provided with the
 *    distribution.
 *
 * 3. The end-user documentation included with the redistribution, if
 *    any, must include the following acknowlegement:  
 *       "This product includes software developed by the 
 *        Apache Software Foundation (http://www.apache.org/)."
 *    Alternately, this acknowlegement may appear in the software itself,
 *    if and wherever such third-party acknowlegements normally appear.
 *
 * 4. The names "The Jakarta Project", "Tomcat", and "Apache Software
 *    Foundation" must not be used to endorse or promote products derived
 *    from this software without prior written permission. For written 
 *    permission, please contact apache@apache.org.
 *
 * 5. Products derived from this software may not be called "Apache"
 *    nor may "Apache" appear in their names without prior written
 *    permission of the Apache Group.
 *
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED ``AS IS'' AND ANY EXPRESSED OR IMPLIED
 * WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES
 * OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE
 * DISCLAIMED.  IN NO EVENT SHALL THE APACHE SOFTWARE FOUNDATION OR
 * ITS CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL,
 * SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT
 * LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF
 * USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND
 * ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY,
 * OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT
 * OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF
 * SUCH DAMAGE.
 * ====================================================================
 *
 * This software consists of voluntary contributions made by many
 * individuals on behalf of the Apache Software Foundation.  For more
 * information on the Apache Software Foundation, please see
 * <http://www.apache.org/>.
 *
 */
```

But it's working in detecting short comment.

Program catch lot of error

[image: code]
[image: error]

Comment: please make a minimal code example reproducing your problem. most of the code you posted is irrelevant.

Comment: What are you trying to do in the first place? Not quite sure if I understand your objective.

Comment: @1010 : i sorry, but it's my problem i don't know what should i do, but it's just my problem and other of long comment.

Comment: @Gosu : my problem in there `Pattern.compile("(/\\*(.|[\\n]|(\\*+([^*/]|[\\r\\n])))*\\*+/)|(//.*)")`. can't detect long comment

Comment: @newbie: Your gui code is irrelevant. I suggest you edit your post keeping the regular expression, the comment that fails and the error stacktrace. Other users may get a hint how to solve similar problems.

Comment: i have edit my post, but my error not printed in stackTrace

Comment: Do you have to deal with incomplete input, in which `*/` is not properly closed?

Comment: No, I don't. I need comment detection which start from `/*` to `*/` or start from `//`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the Java regular expression engine is recursion-based. That means that the regular expression has to be optimized to produce fewer backtrackings. Yet I cannot see which backtracking produces this call stack.

Following proposals work for larger comments:

- `Pattern.compile("(/\\*.*?\\*/)", Pattern.DOTALL)` (matches only /* .. */)
- `Pattern.compile("(/\\*([^\\*]|(\\*(?!/))+)*+\\*+/)|(//.*)")`

Explanation:

- `(.| ...)*` usually produces backtrackings because `.` matches (almost) all character and the other alternatives are usually also matching `.*` - so the first action is to eliminate `.`. In your case replace it by `[^\\*]`.
- `[^\\*]|[\\n]` == `[^\\*]` so remove `[\\n]`
- `[^*/]|[\\r\\n]` == `[^*/]` so remove `[\\r\\n]`
- to prevent backtracking we use `*+` after the content loop (possessive regular expression). But this requires that the last dot is not consumed by the content loop. So we insert a negative loopahead for `/` after the matched `*`, i.e. `(\\*(?!/))+`

Comment: that's great, it seem work for me. thanks for your explanation.
i'll try it in my another long comment.

Comment: The SOE is due to the greedy/lazy repetition of some variable length sub pattern. Possessive quantifier is the way to go here, since it doesn't require stack linear to the length of the pattern.

Comment: Thats right - I'll remove the second solution (the correct one is equivalent to one of Alan Moore's)